# Developing an iPad application without a Mac

Tags: ios

I've been a long time lurker on this site, so here's my first question.

I was hired this summer at a local medical software company to develop an ipad application. I'm a CS major with 2 years left of school and have no experience with ipad apps but consider myself a proficent programmer. I have started drawing diagrams and laid out the framework of the application (I was given very vague requirements). So my first question is where do I start? I do not own a MAC. They want the app to work on ipad specifically and other platforms are an added bonus. What do I use to start development?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post

Answer (score 2):

My best bet is use phonegap. This will help you render out your code to any platform. But nothing is better than going native to make use of the best. Hence for iPad apps Mac is a necessity.

Comment: @user3786368 Always click the tick mark if the response resolved your question. This way it moves to the answered section and does not stay in unanswered.